# Unable to manipulate packet timestamp with Scapy

Tags: python, timestamp, ethernet, scapy, packets

I'm willing to forge a packet with any `timestamp` I choose.

I've written the following piece of code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime

pkt1 = scapy.all.Ether()
pkt1.src = "01:01:76:05:8c:0d"
pkt1.dst = "1b:1b:1b:1b:01:01"
pkt1.time = 12345678
str(pkt1)
print datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt1.time)
```

What I get in the packet is only the current time and not `"12345678"`.

Does anyone has an idea why this doesn't work?
Is there any other way to preform time manipulation over packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try your code with the latest Scapy version from the repository, it seems to work.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scapy.all import *
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> pkt1 = scapy.all.Ether()
>>> pkt1.src = "01:01:76:05:8c:0d"
>>> pkt1.dst = "1b:1b:1b:1b:01:01"
>>> pkt1.time = 12345678
>>> str(pkt1)
'\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01\x01v\x05\x8c\r\x00\x00'
>>> print datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt1.time)
1970-05-23 22:21:18
>>>
```

What do you get?

Have you tried with the latest version (`hg clone http://bb.secdev.org/scapy`) from the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/wiki/Home)?